# How to implement the iterative way to change the filename reading and how to combine result into single excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, loops

I am new to python. Have a task that have to find some of the following for all the excel files(1.xlsx-350.xlsx) around 350 excel files,  which contained in single folder(Videos). and written following code it works fine but it is time consuming, manually have to change file name every iteration. even in the end of the process, I have to combine all 350 excel file operated data into single excel file. But in my code it overwrite each and every iteration. please help me to resolve this problem.

```
data12 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Videos\1.xlsx')
gxt = data12.iloc [:,0]
gyan = data12.iloc [:,1]
int= gyan.iloc[98:197]
comp= gyan.iloc[197:252]
seg= gyan.iloc[252:319]
A= max(int)   
B= max(comp)  
C= min(comp)  
D= max(seg) 
s = pd.Series([A, B, C, D])
frame_data= [gyan, comp, seg, stat]
result = pd.concat(frame_data)
result.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='modify_data', index=False)
```

thank you for helping.

Comment: Is it that you have 350 .xlsx files in total and you have to run the above code for 350 times? Also does the loc mentioned for gxt, gyan,int and comp change? Also you have used stat in frame_data, can you explain what this is? It will be helpful to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, stat also dataset like seg. i forgot mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
import os

# Give an excel filename and worksheet name 
output='C:\Users\Videos\output.xlsx'
worksheet = 'Sheet'
wb = Workbook() 

# If file not present at location, then create one
if os.path.isfile(output):
    print('File Present')
else:
    print('Creatted New file')
    ws = wb.create_sheet(worksheet)
    wb.save(output)

# Loop for all 350 files
for i in range(1, 351):
    print('File {}:'.format(i))
    data12 = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Videos\{}.xlsx'.format(i))
    gxt = data12.iloc [:,0]
    gyan = data12.iloc [:,1]
    int= gyan.iloc[8:19]
    comp= gyan.iloc[19:25]
    seg= gyan.iloc[25:31]
    A= max(int)   
    B= max(comp)  
    C= min(comp)
    D= max(seg) 
    s = pd.Series([A, B, C, D])
    
    frame_data= [gyan, comp, seg]
    result = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat(frame_data))
    ws = wb.active
    result_list = result.to_numpy()
    print('Total rows = ', len(result_list))
    for row in result_list.tolist():
        ws.append(row)
    wb.save(output)
```

This will help to run through all 350 files and save it to output file.
Also make changes to frame_data accordingly. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Flowing code gives you all the files in a folder

```
filenames = listdir(r'C:\Users\Videos')
count = 1
for file in filenames:
    print (file)
....... 
#At the end
output = "output-" + str(count) + ".xlsx"
count = count + 1
result = pd.concat(frame_data)
result.to_excel(output, sheet_name='modify_data', index=False)
```

For the master file, you can save the data in a pandas dataframe and keep appending each file in the loop.

Comment: thanks for help. but output file (master file) does not combine all the excel file data. final output file carry have only final operation values. it overwrite the master file every time.